# How to handle html form in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a html page to parse and form in it looking like that:

```
<select id="limit" name="limit" class="inputbox input-mini" size="1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="0">All</option>
</select>
```

This form affects on how page looks(limit of displayed items). How can I change an option to "All" and submit this form to get all elements?

Comment: If you select `All` in the Dropdown-Menu, a value of `0` will be sent for the item `limit` in the form that surrounds this checkbox if that's what you're asking? Please show us your code if that's not what you want to know...

Comment: @Maurice how to send `0` for the item `limit` in the form in python?

Comment: Please check out [how HTML forms work](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) - in a nutshell you send a HTTP Request with the method that's determined by the `method` parameter to the url that's determined by the `action` parameter of the form and encode your value for limit in the payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in my comment I'd advise you to research, [how HTML forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and inputs work.

The URL you need to send your data to is either determined by the `action` parameter or encoded in some Javascript function.
The HTTP method you need to use is set in the `method` parameter of the form or `get` by default.

Here's how you could use that in python:

Adapted from the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) of the `requests` module.

```
import requests

# You might need to choose the get method here depending on the value of the forms method parameter
response = requests.post("your-url.here", data={'limit': 0})

print(response.text)
```

---

**Edit**

In response to the Comments I'll add the example for `get` Requests as well

```
import requests

response = requests.get("your-url.here", params={'limit': 0})

print(response.text)
```

The version has the advantage compared to the comment, that it will take care of URL-Encoding special characters for you.

Comment: This code describes how to send a post request. If your form uses a get request you need to use:
    response = requests.get("your-url.here?limit=0")

Comment: @SerAlejo I added a slight variation of your proposed solution to my answer that will take care of potentially necessary URL-encoding as well.